# Nestjs not receiving data service to Controller

Tags: nestjs

I am looking for a response from userService .. but it is returning a null value..
I have consoled the data in userSerice it's showing here.

may be my controller is giving a response before receiving value from userService.

how can I solve this?

usercontroller

```
import {
  Controller,
  Post,
  Body,
  Get,
  Param,
  Patch,
  Delete,
} from '@nestjs/common';

import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Controller('users')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}


  @Post('/login')
  async login(
    @Body('email') userEmail,
    @Body('password') userPassword
  ) {
    const token = await this.userService.Login(userEmail, userPassword)
    console.log(token, 'token')
    return token;
  }
}
```

Userservice :

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';


import { Model } from 'mongoose';

import { User } from './user.model';

import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import { resolve } from 'dns';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<User>,
  ) { }

  async Login(email: string, password: string) {
    const user = await this.userModel.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      console.log("User does exist on the database.");
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
        if (!result) {
          throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        const authJwtToken = jwt.sign({ name: user.name, email: user.email, role: user.role }, "testSecreate");
        const response = { name: user.name, email: user.email, role: user.role, token: authJwtToken }
        console.log(response)
        return response;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: bcrypt.compare and other jwt functions should be called with await.

Comment: it's showing error..   when I am adding await before jwt.sign    const authJwtToken = await jwt.sign({ name: user.name, email: user.email, role: user.role }, "testSecreate");

Comment: and what is it?

Comment: please see the comment in answer

Comment: /media/rabbani/_dde_data1/nestjs/contact-product-auth/dist/auth/user.service.js:57
[0]                 const authJwtToken = yield jwt.sign({ name: user.name, email: user.email, role: user.role }, "testSecreate");
[0]                                      ^^^^^
[0] 
[0] SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)

Comment: what is ` yield` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232773/discussion-between-tushar-roy-and-rabbani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tushar has n all right answer, but it's still mixing promises and callbacks, which I think should be avoided if possible. You can use this instead to not have any callbacks and just use `async/await` and promises throughout the method

```js
import {
  Injectable,
  NotFoundException,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectModel } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

import { Model } from "mongoose";

import { User } from "./user.model";

import * as bcrypt from "bcrypt";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(@InjectModel("User") private readonly userModel: Model<User>) {}

  async Login(email: string, password: string) {
    const user = await this.userModel.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      console.log("User does exist on the database.");
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    const result = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!result) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    const authJwtToken = await jwt.sign(
      { name: user.name, email: user.email, role: user.role },
      "testSecreate"
    );
    const response = {
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      role: user.role,
      token: authJwtToken,
    };
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Now, the `console.log(response)` will fire before `console.log('token', token)` in your controller method, and the flow will *look* synchronous while actually being asynchronous in nature.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';


import { Model } from 'mongoose';

import { User } from './user.model';

import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import { resolve } from 'dns';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<User>,
  ) { }

  async Login(email: string, password: string) {
    const user = await this.userModel.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      console.log("User does exist on the database.");
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

     await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
        if (!result) {
          throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        const authJwtToken = await jwt.sign({ name: user.name, email: user.email, role: user.role }, "testSecreate");
        const response = { name: user.name, email: user.email, role: user.role, token: authJwtToken }
        console.log(response)
        return response;
      });
  }
}
```

**NOTE**
The asynchronous method will be executed in parallel with your main program, so your console.log will be done before the callback function inside `bcrypt.compare`. You will see always 'oops, it was false'.

Comment: /media/rabbani/_dde_data1/nestjs/contact-product-auth/dist/auth/user.service.js:57
[0]                 const authJwtToken = yield jwt.sign({ name: user.name, email: user.email, role: user.role }, "testSecreate");
[0]                                      ^^^^^
[0] 
[0] SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word

Comment: are you using generators?? seems to be an error from there.